# Pandas After merging the same values, the column name becomes 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data structure.

[image]

```
+--------------------------+----------------------+
¦            test1         ¦          test2       ¦
¦--------------------------¦----------------------+
¦ https: // test.com / 123 ¦           st1        ¦
¦ https: // test.com / 123 ¦           st2        ¦
¦ https: // test.com / 1234¦           st3        ¦
¦ https: // test.com / 1234¦           st4        ¦
+----------------------+--------------------------+
```

I want to merge the values of test2 based on the same test1 column values

I tried the following code

```
import pandas as pd

test = 'test.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel(test)

df_isnull_have_keywords = df1.groupby(by='test1').apply(
    lambda x: [','.join('%s' % key for key in x['test2'])])

df_isnull_have_keywords.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

But in the output, the test2 column is 0

[image]

I don't know，please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the index and you should be fine:

```
df1.groupby('test1')['test2'].agg(list).reset_index()
```

output:

```
                   test1       test2
0   https://test.com/123  [st1, st2]
1  https://test.com/1234  [st3, st4]
```